# Swift - Impossible to use "registerNib" on my tableView to add a custom cell

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, cell

I'm just figuring out how to add custom cells to a tableView in Swift. I watched a lot of tutorials and they all say at some point to use something like `tableView.registerNib` which is not working for me !

This is the code I'm using in my tableViewController class :

```
var nib = UINib(nibName: "ViewExerciceCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ExerciceCell")
```

When I try to build, I have an error on the second line which says :

> Cannot invoke 'registerNib' with an argument list of type '(UINib,
>   forCellReuseIdentifier: String)'.

What can I do ? All the tutorials and other answers about custom cells are using this code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is `tableView` declared? Note that if `tableView` is an optional, you cannot call a method directly, you have to use the `tableView?.registerNib` notation.

Comment: My tableView is declared as an Outlet : `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. The only problem I can imagine is that you have a typo there and you haven't copied the typo here correctly.

Comment: How you created the cell? Using code or nib?

Comment: Is there a way to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 5):

I'm using following code inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as UITableViewCell
if cell == nil {
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as UITableViewCell!
}

return cell
```

If you have your custom cell in storyboard or .xib file, don't forget to set `Identifier`(in this case CustomCell) in Attributes inspector

Comment: Seems wasteful to register the Nib over and over here. Do it once, on load.

Comment: I second @drew..'s comment. Registring a cell is just a one-time requirement. So doesn't require to be written within ```cellForRowAtIndexPath:``` method.

Answer (score 3):

After some head-banging I realized my error:

Instead of "forCellReuseIdentifier" I was supposed to use forCellWithReuseIdentifier. With so many things changing with Swift so swiftly, Its hard to keep up with all the changes. Hope this helps.

Solution that worked for me:

```
self.collectionView!.register(UINib(nibName: "CategoryCVCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCVCell")
```

Comment: That's funny. When I tried to use "forCellWithReuseIdentifier", I got an error and had to change it back to "forCellReuseIdentifier", not that either one fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ok... I don't know what was the problem, but removing the file reference of my `cell.xib` in my project and adding it again just solved the problem.
I already had some problems resolved like that in the past.

Thank you all for your quick answers !

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was changing this:

```
collectionView.register(MovieCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "moviesCollectionView")
```

To this:

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "MovieCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "moviesCollectionView")
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used a generic function , which I've called like this.

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: R.reuseIdentifier.uploadDocHeaderCell.identifier, bundle:nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: R.reuseIdentifier.uploadDocHeaderCell.identifier)
```

The generic class was used from github, you can just use the following function though:

```
public func register<Resource: NibResourceType & ReuseIdentifierType>(_ nibResource: Resource)
    where Resource.ReusableType: UICollectionViewCell
  {
    register(UINib(resource: nibResource), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: nibResource.identifier)
  }
```

The link for the GitHub resource is:

[Link attached for reference](https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift.Library)

Answer (score 0):

In your viewDidLoad add following lines:

```
let nibName = UINib(nibName: "cell_name", bundle:nil)
        collectionView.register(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell_name")
```

And then in your cellForItemAt method,add the following lines:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell_name", for: indexPath)as! cell_name
```

Make sure to give the identifier to the cell.